# changing display property with jquery hover

Tags: jquery, css, angularjs

I have pictures of different staff members and when the mouse hovers over the image I want `display:none;` to change to `display:block;` on the .staffInfo class.  I feel like what I have should work, but nothing is happening. I have no console errors.  This is an Angular project.

HTML

```
<div class="col-lg-12 staffBlock">
     <div ng-repeat="people in staff">
      <div class="col-lg-4 staffCards">
       <img src="{{people.image}}" alt="" class="img-rounded img-responsive">
       <div class="staffInfo">
        <h3>Name:{{people.name}}</h3>
        <p>Likes:{{people.likes}}</p>
       </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
```

SCSS

```
.staffCards{
 margin-top:10px;
  .staffInfo{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0px;
  height:100%;
  width:65%;
  border-radius:3%;
  background-color:black;
  opacity:.6;
  color:white;
 }
}
```

jQuery

```
$('.staffInfo').hover(function(){
 $(this).css('display', 'block');
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `ng-show` directive to make it AngularWay.

```
<div class="staffInfo" ng-show="people.isHover" 
   ng-mouseenter="people.isHover=true" 
   ng-mouseleave="isHover=false">
      <h3>Name:{{people.name}}</h3>
      <p>Likes:{{people.likes}}</p>
</div>
```

Comment: doesn't seem to be working. nothing is happening when hovering over.

Comment: @AndrewLevy it should work..how are you rendering this DOM?

Comment: could you explain rendering this DOM? :0

Comment: This basic idea should work but you might want to change ng-show to ng-style or ng-class to change the css property or add a class based on the isHover scope variable.

Comment: @csmithmaui why do you think like that it needs to be change?

Comment: @PankajParkar sorry, I just realized that he is just trying to show or hide the div...I was looking at it as just applying a css property change and not really realizing what effect he was shooting for.  You are correct!

Comment: @AndrewLevy oh..its pure angular way..using `ng-repeat` .. let me create working plunkr for you...

Comment: @PankajParkar I could be missing something but wouldn't you need to put the ng-mouseenter and ng-mouseleave on the image or a div around the image, because the div with class `staffInfo` will never get shown in order for the mouse to enter and trigger the variable used in ng-show?

Comment: @csmithmaui yes..those elements are not visible so how could mousenter & leave event will work

Answer (score 0):

You have applied display:none on #staffCards but you're changing the display property of #staffInfo on hover.
So even when the staffInfo is block, staffCards is still set to `display:none`

Comment: .staffInfo is set to display:none.  not .staffCards